# How can I configure my project.clj so that Leiningen finds my sources under a non-standard directory structure?

Tags: clojure, leiningen

It seems Leiningen's *compile* task looks for source packages to start immediately under the **/src** directory. I use both Java and Clojure in my project, so my **/src** directory looks like this:

```
/src/java/myapp
/src/clojure/myapp
```

Right now Leiningen is looking for **/src/myapp** and it's failing out during the *compile*.

Related, I'd like to know how to manually add directories to the classpath for Leiningen's *compile* and *repl* tasks. For example, Enlive's **deftemplate** function will search the classpath for a named template file. Adding **/templates** to the classpath would be required for my project to build and run properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will be [fixed](http://github.com/ato/leiningen/commit/fb95c5ef57a554081c012df139b2751344cc970a) in Leiningen 1.0 which is currently looking good for a release in the next week or so.  Hopefully someone writes a javac plugin for Leiningen too; it should be easy to write as Lein bundles ant so you could just reuse ant's javac task.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `:root` value in your project file?

Looking at the source code for the compile command, it will process only Clojure files anyway and will look for these files under `(file (:root project) "src")` , so you could set `:root` to point to "src/clojure/" but would still need a symlink so that "src/clojure/src/" exists...

Comment: This didn't immediately work, though I didn't play with it too much